# PHP MySQL find best matches

Tags: php, mysql

HI and sorry for my english in beginning.
So I have tables like this

```
--
-- Table structure for table `peoples`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `peoples` (
`id_people` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `peoples`
--

INSERT INTO `peoples` (`id_people`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Igor');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `peoples_skills`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `peoples_skills` (
  `id_people` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_skill` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `peoples_skills`
--

INSERT INTO `peoples_skills` (`id_people`, `id_skill`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 3);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `skills`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `skills` (
`id_skills` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `skills`
--

INSERT INTO `skills` (`id_skills`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Analytical'),
(2, 'Accuracy'),
(3, 'Coaching'),
(4, 'Decision making ');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `weapons`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `weapons` (
`id_weapon` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `weapons`
--

INSERT INTO `weapons` (`id_weapon`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'weapon 1'),
(2, 'weapon 2');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `weapons_skills`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `weapons_skills` (
  `id_weapon` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_skill` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '// skill required to use reapon'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `weapons_skills`
--

INSERT INTO `weapons_skills` (`id_weapon`, `id_skill`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(2, 3);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `peoples`
--
ALTER TABLE `peoples`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_people`);

--
-- Indexes for table `peoples_skills`
--
ALTER TABLE `peoples_skills`
 ADD KEY `peoples_skills-id_people_idx` (`id_people`), ADD KEY `peoples_skills-id_skil_idx` (`id_skill`);

--
-- Indexes for table `skills`
--
ALTER TABLE `skills`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_skills`);

--
-- Indexes for table `weapons`
--
ALTER TABLE `weapons`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_weapon`);

--
-- Indexes for table `weapons_skills`
--
ALTER TABLE `weapons_skills`
 ADD KEY `weapons_skills-id_skill_idx` (`id_skill`), ADD KEY `weapons_skills-id_weapon` (`id_weapon`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `peoples`
--
ALTER TABLE `peoples`
MODIFY `id_people` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `skills`
--
ALTER TABLE `skills`
MODIFY `id_skills` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `weapons`
--
ALTER TABLE `weapons`
MODIFY `id_weapon` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `peoples_skills`
--
ALTER TABLE `peoples_skills`
ADD CONSTRAINT `peoples_skills-id_people` FOREIGN KEY (`id_people`) REFERENCES `peoples` (`id_people`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `peoples_skills-id_skil` FOREIGN KEY (`id_skill`) REFERENCES `skills` (`id_skills`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

--
-- Constraints for table `weapons_skills`
--
ALTER TABLE `weapons_skills`
ADD CONSTRAINT `weapons_skills-id_weapon` FOREIGN KEY (`id_weapon`) REFERENCES `weapons` (`id_weapon`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `weapons_skills-id_skill` FOREIGN KEY (`id_skill`) REFERENCES `skills` (`id_skills`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

You can see that I have tables Peoples, Weapons, Skills and linking table people_skills, weapons_skills (relations many to many), I need to find best matches weapon for people by checking matching skills if is possible in percentage, if weapon have all skills like people it will be 100%, no same skills it will be 0% etc, its possible to get it in some queries? or using PHP? I need to find good way, or another structure to database? but I need to have relations many to many

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the job:

```
select 
p.*, w.*,
COUNT(DISTINCT(ps.id_skill)) as total_skills, 
SUM(IF(ws.id_skill=ps.id_skill, 1, 0)) as matching_skills, 
SUM(IF(ws.id_skill=ps.id_skill, 1, 0)) / COUNT(DISTINCT(ps.id_skill)) * 100 as matching_percentage  
from peoples_skills ps
CROSS JOIN weapons_skills ws
JOIN peoples p ON p.id_people=ps.id_people
JOIN weapons w ON w.id_weapon=ws.id_weapon
GROUP BY p.id_people,w.id_weapon
ORDER BY matching_percentage DESC
```

`matching_percentage` is the value that you want. The results are ordered from the best match to the worst.